# how to create a 3d image using set of 2d images

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d

I have a set of images of a room taken at different angles.i want to make 3d map of the room using these images using matlab or any other software.please help me.

Comment: I think we need a bit more explanation. This question is far too open-ended. What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: Regarding "or any other software", this is a duplicate: [Convert 2d images to 3d model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532184/convert-2d-images-to-3d-model), [Creating a 3D effect from a 2D image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846982/creating-a-3d-effect-from-a-2d-image)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [krpano software](http://krpano.com/), it works with Flash and HTML5/JS.  Worked for me :)